# Setting scrollToTime makes the calendar loose current scroll position on resize or drag-and-drop

Tags: react-big-calendar

I am setting the following props to react-big-calendar to make the calendar scroll to 10:00 on opening.

```
    scrollToTime={moment()
                .set({ h: 10, m: 0 })
                .toDate()}
```

However, not surprisingly this leads to rerendering of the calendar when resizing or dropping an event. Is there any way to combat this?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-drag-and-drop-events-between-months-tphkw